# cannot assign value to readonly property UIButton

Tags: objective-c

I just started ios development with Objective C. I am trying to develop a simple app that has a label and a button.When the button is clicked the label content and title of the button should change. However when I try to change title of `UIButton` I get the error

```
Error :Assignment to readonly property
```

This is my basic code

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic , weak) IBOutlet UILabel* labelName;
@property(nonatomic , weak) IBOutlet UIButton* greetButton;

-(IBAction)greetClickedAction:(id)sender; //Button connected here to get the click event
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)greetClickedAction:(id)sender
{
    _labelName.text  = @"Label Changed";    //This Works fine
    greetButton.currentTitle=@"New Title";  //Error :Assignment to readonly property
}

@end
```

My question is why am i getting the error when assigning something to UIButton and not to UILabel ? How can I fix this ?

**Update:**

I can remove the readonly error using as suggested by @dasblinkenlight by doing the following but the code still does not change the title of the button

```
_greetButton.titleLabel.text = @"New Title";
```

Answer (score 1):

`greetButton.currentTitle` is for checking the text on the button. It cannot be set directly, because it is computed. You could set the text property of the [`greetButton.titleLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel), or call `setTitle:forState:` instead:

```
[_greetButton setTitle: @"New Title" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: yes that removed the read only error (also as a correction its suppose to be _greetButton since I did not syntehsize) also however the title did not change the text of the button

Comment: The title of the button still did not change

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following once:

```
[_greetButton setTitle:@"New title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```